# How to loop through string and check if there are unmatched letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am looping through an array of letters, after each click a letter will be added. And there is also a string (var **word**) that will randomly be chosen, and the expected result is that it have to return true each time when there is an unmatching letter being added to the '**currentArray**'. So after each click on an unmatched letter this function should still work!

For example if **currentArray** = ['b', 'o', 'l'] 
**word** is 'bob'. It should return true once....

I tried this one before, but as you might know this is the wrong way -->

**currentArray.filter((word) => word !== word)**

Comment: What about use `localeCompare()`method to evaluate two strings? Or you need to compare strictly two arrays of letters ?

Comment: what is your conditionals?? if array contains `b,o,l` and the word is `bob` is this true even through the word does not contain `l` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following code will help you.

```
let currentArray = ['b', 'o', 'l'];

let pattern = "bob";

let notIncluded = currentArray.filter(char => pattern.indexOf(char) === -1);

console.log(notIncluded);
```

Comment: it should work even when the user add a letter to the currentArray.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that should do the trick.

```js
const arr = ['b', 'o', 'l'];
const arr2 = ['b', 'o']
const word = 'bob';

let out = arr.filter(el => word.split('').indexOf(el) === -1).length > 0;
let out2 = arr2.filter(el => word.split('').indexOf(el) === -1).length > 0;

console.log(out, out2)
```

You're essentially filtering out elements of the array if a letter from the word is present, then check if the length is greater than 0.

I think this is what you were requesting.

Comment: This seems a working solution, but the problem I have now is that if i add letter 'b' or '0' it will also return true.

Comment: another problem that the boolean will be true, when the use has been clicked on l, and any letter clicked afterwards will return true either.....

Comment: @frontend If you can give specific examples of how the array and word should be formatted to produce the false positives, I can probably update the answer to fulfill the requirements.  I'm just not sure what it is you need it to do right now though.  Also, if this answer was helpful, please upvote it and select it as the correct answer :).